# How to join a dataframe with a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, join, pivot-table

Here is my dataframe

| ID | Sum total | Sum partial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 40 | 25 |
| A2 | 70 | 50 |
| A3 | 100 | 40 |

I would like to build a third column based on the following pivot table given grid let's say:

| Sum total interval\sum partial interval | 0-30 | 30-55 | 55-70 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-50 | 0.10 | 0.17 | 0.22 |
| 50-75 | 0.14 | 0.18 | 0.25 |
| 75-100 | 0.20 | 0.27 | 0.38 |

Which would give this expected result:

| ID | Sum total | Sum partial | Ratio given by grid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 40 | 25 | 0.10 |
| A2 | 70 | 50 | 0.18 |
| A3 | 100 | 40 | 0.27 |

I would like to know what is the most convenient way to do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `pd.IntervalIndex` and `loc`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Copy input from question above
df1 = pd.read_clipboard() # Copy input from question above

df1 = df1.set_index(df1.columns[0]) #Create index with first column

#Create IntervalIndex from ranges in index and column headers
df1.columns = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays([0,30,55],[30,55,70]) 
df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays([0,50,75],[50,75,100])

#Test getting value by stacking columns and index to create multiIndex
df1.stack().loc[(40,25)] #returns .1

# Create list of tuples for "lookup" in df1 with zip
df['Ratio Give by grid'] = df1.stack().loc[zip(df['Sum total'], df['Sum partial'])].to_numpy()

df
```

Output:

```
   ID  Sum total  Sum partial  Ratio Give by grid
0  A1         40           25                0.10
1  A2         70           50                0.18
2  A3        100           40                0.27
```